# How to use LOWER case in WHERE condition for Character varying Array column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have my query like this.

```
SELECT ColumnX, ColumnY 
FROM table 
WHERE columnA @> ARRAY['SEARCH_Text']::varchar[]
```

Here `columnA` is a `CHARACTER VARYING[]` column.

It is working for case sensitive. But I want to apply LOWER case for my search_text i.e. when i my search text is in lowercase like this `'search_text'` I want to get the data. How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the [`citext`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html) data type or a [case insensitive, non-deterministic ICU collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/collation.html#id-1.6.10.4.5.7.5).

Or (better) you normalize your data model and don't use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Make and use an immutable function:

```
create function lower(varchar[]) returns varchar[] immutable language SQL as $$ 
  select lower($1::text)::varchar[];
$$ parallel safe;

SELECT ColumnX, ColumnY 
FROM table 
WHERE lower(columnA) @> lower(ARRAY['SEARCH_Text'])
```